# Precalculate numbers of records for each possible combination

Tags: mysql, database, count

I have a mySQL database table containing cellphones information like this:

```
ID   Brand   Model  Price Type   Size
==== =====   =====  ===== ====== ====
1    Apple   A71    3128  A      40
2    Samsung B7C    3128  B      20
3    Apple   ZX5    3128  A      30
4    Huawei  Q32    2574  B      40
5    Apple   A21    2574  A      25
6    Apple   A71    3369  A      30
7    Samsung A71    7413  C      40
```

Now I want to create another table, that would contain counts for every possible combination of the parameters.

```
Params                                         Count  
============================================== =======  
ALL                                            1000000
Brand(Apple)                                   20000
Brand(Apple,Samsung)                           40000
Brand(Apple),Model(A71)                        7100
Brand(Apple),Type(A)                           6000
Brand(Apple),Model(A71,B7C),Type(A,B)          7
Model(A71)                                     12514
Model(A71,B7C)                                 26584
Model(A71),Type(A)                             6521
Model(A71),Type(A,B)                           8958
Model(A71),Type(A,B),Size(40)                  85
```

And so on for every possible combination. I was thinking about creating a stored procedure (that i would execute periodically), that would perform queries with every existing condition like that, but I am a little stuck on how exactly should it look like. Or is there a better way how to do this?

**Edit:** the reason why I want to store information like this is to be able to show number of results in filter in client application, like in the picture.

[image: showing number of results]

I would like to **create index** on the `Params` column to be able to get the `Count` **number for given hash instantly**, improving performance.

I also tried querying and caching the values dynamically, but I want to try this approach as well, so I can compare which one is more effective.

This is how I am calculating the counts now:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE Brand IN ('Apple');
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE Brand IN ('Apple', 'Samsung');
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM products WHERE Brand IN ('Apple') AND Model IN ('A71');
```

etc.

Comment: Your description is still ambiguous. Please create a representative data sample and the complete expected result and specifically describe how counts are calculated..

Comment: Sounds like [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I edited the question, hopefully it will clarify more what Im trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ROLLUP` for this.

```
SELECT 
model, type, size, COUNT(*)
FROM mytab
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
WITH ROLLUP
```

With your sample data, we get the following:

```
| model | type | size | COUNT(*) |
| ----- | ---- | ---- | -------- |
| A21   | A    | 25   | 1        |
| A21   | A    |      | 1        |
| A21   |      |      | 1        |
| A71   | A    | 30   | 1        |
| A71   | A    | 40   | 1        |
| A71   | A    |      | 2        |
| A71   | C    | 40   | 1        |
| A71   | C    |      | 1        |
| A71   |      |      | 3        |
| B7C   | B    | 20   | 1        |
| B7C   | B    |      | 1        |
| B7C   |      |      | 1        |
| Q32   | B    | 40   | 1        |
| Q32   | B    |      | 1        |
| Q32   |      |      | 1        |
| ZX5   | A    | 30   | 1        |
| ZX5   | A    |      | 1        |
| ZX5   |      |      | 1        |
|       |      |      | 7        |
```

The subtotals are present in the rows with null values in different columns, and the total is the last row where all group by columns are null.

Comment: This is useful, however i forgot to mention (I already edited my question) that I need only 1 column to specify the params (using some sort of a unique string), so that I can index it.